# Datagridview not displaying data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 data grid views (ValidationRun is master, Results is detail). I am binding this to a dataset which I know contains data - I can see it when I debug. However, I get not data in the grids.

Any ideas?

```
/class level objects
private DataGridView dgvValidationRun = new DataGridView();
private BindingSource bsValidationRun = new BindingSource();
private DataGridView dgvResults = new DataGridView();
private BindingSource bsResults = new BindingSource();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {    

        // Bind the DataGridView controls to the BindingSource    
        // components and load the data from the database.    
        dgvValidationRun.DataSource = bsValidationRun;    
        dgvResults.DataSource = bsResults;    
        GetData();    

        // Resize the master DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded data.    
        dgvValidationRun.AutoResizeColumns();    

        // Configure the details DataGridView so that its columns automatically    
        // adjust their widths when the data changes.    
        dgvResults.AutoSizeColumnsMode =    
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;    

    }

private void GetData()    
    {    
        try    
        {    
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XMLValidate.Properties.Settings.ValidationResultsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);    

            // Create a DataSet.    
            DataSet data = new DataSet();    
            data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;    

            // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.    
            SqlDataAdapter daValidationRun = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ValidationRun", connection);    
            daValidationRun.Fill(data, "ValidationRun");    

            // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.    
            SqlDataAdapter daResults = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Result", connection);    
            daResults.Fill(data, "Result");    

            // Establish a relationship between the two tables.    
            DataRelation relRunResult = new DataRelation("RunResult",    
                data.Tables["ValidationRun"].Columns["RunId"],    
                data.Tables["Result"].Columns["RunId"]);    
            data.Relations.Add(relRunResult);    

            // Bind the run data connector to the Run table.    
            bsValidationRun.DataSource = data;    
            bsValidationRun.DataMember = "ValidationRun";    

            // Bind the results data connector to the results data connector,    
            // using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the     
            // details table based on the current row in the master table.     
            bsResults.DataSource = bsValidationRun;    
            bsResults.DataMember = "RunResult";    

            dgvValidationRun.AutoGenerateColumns = true;    
            dgvValidationRun.Refresh();    
        }    
        catch (Exception ex)    
        {    
            int i = 1;    
        }    
    }
```

Comment: is dgvValidationRun added to your form controls?

Comment: I suspect something very trivial, please remove your catch and let see if some exception occurs.

Comment: Many thanks nawfal, that was the problem. I had a couple of data grids that I'd added to the form via the designer but forgot to give them the same name as the code-behind - doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks nawfal, that was the problem. I had a couple of data grids that I'd added to the form via the designer but forgot to give them the same name as the code-behind - doh!